# Help with uml modelling and xcode

Tags: objective-c, uml

I would like to create UML class diagrams for my project in XCode 3.

I have the following objective-c code:

```
-(IBAction) showDatesid:sender;
{
getDatesController *dateAndPrice =[[getDatesController alloc]initWithNibName:@"getDatesController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:dateAndPrice animated:YES];

}
```

Is it an agregation, composition or usage in uml?

With XCode 3, in the class model->quick model, it shows me just inheritance, I can't show other uml link ?

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do, but "usage" might be the closest UML term to your piece of code.

Comment: I want to make th classes diagram for my project

Answer (score 0):

If you select your project file, the first file in the browser and then ask the UML pattern, the whole hierarchy will be displayed.

Comment: yes whole classes are displayed but there are only heritage .There are no agregation and no composition ... UML pattern you mean design and then quick uml model ?

Comment: Hum i see. I don't think you can do it with xCode 3 or 4... I think you probably have better time to look for  another UML tool... Maybe you will find smth here : http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/xcode/246332-uml-xcode-plugin.html